# Spring boot localization from database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, localization, internationalization

I would like to implement localization on my spring boot application. Localization based on message bundle is working fine. But I need to implement the same from reading locale message from database based on my master table data. What is the best practice to implement this. I want to implement this solution with minimal changes on my existing entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MessageSource is not, in my opinion, useful for fetching a list of employees by locale.

It is important to understand that the MessageSource is an API (MessageSourceInterface) that can select a text (for example a translation) using code and locale. Whether you use the code and/or locale in your MessageSource implementation to select a string is up to you. If you look at the MessageSource interface, you will see that getMessage() returns a String, not a list of objects.

Components for example Validation and Thymeleaf use the MessageSource to select a text. You define the code and optional arguments or/and a DefaultMessage.

You may also need to implement a fallback in your MessageSource implementation if the locale is not supported.

The component set the locale.

[Component] <-> [MessageSource] <-> [DataSource]

**Thymeleaf**

```html
<h1 th:text="#{home_headline}"/>
```

You can also use the MessageSource directly.

```java
@Autowired MessageSource messageSource;
String methodeName() {
    return this.messageSource.getMessage("home_headline", null, null, Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
}
```

Comment: My main objective is read master data table values based on locale. But locale related data is stored in locale related key value table.

Comment: Without an example of how the data is structured, I can't give you any advice on how best to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

To read messages from the database, you must implement a custom MessageSource. For this purpose, the MessageSourceInterface must be implemented.

With a database it should look like this.

**MyDatabaseMessageSource**

```java
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable;
import org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MyDatabaseMessageSource implements MessageSource {

    MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyDatabaseMessageSource(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
        String message = this.myRepository.findTranslation(code, locale);
        if (message != null) {
            if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
                message = new MessageFormat(message).format(args);
            }
            return message;
        }
        return defaultMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        String message = this.myRepository.findTranslation(code, locale);
        if (message != null) {
            if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
                message = new MessageFormat(message).format(args);
            }
            return message;
        }
        throw new NoSuchMessageException(code, locale);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        String message = this.myRepository.findTranslation(code, locale);
        if (message != null) {
            return message;
        }
        throw new NoSuchMessageException(code, locale);
    }
}
```

**MessageSourceConfig**

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired MyRepository myRepository;
    @Bean("messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        return new MyDatabaseMessageSource(this.myRepository);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working fine. Now what is the best approach to get list of localized data from a table based on a locale. For example i have a table called employee (code, name and welcome_message). I need to get list of employees with localized welcome_message based on my message resource in db. Where should i implement the getMessage functionality? In findAll or getter method? Or any other best practice for this. I am looking for a generic solution.